# iOS AFNetworking 2.0 XML web service

Tags: ios, xml, xml-parsing, afnetworking-2

I have tried to integrate AFNetworking 2.0 with an XML web service call, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

First of all I've created a shared client by extending **AFHTTPRequestOperationManager**:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedClient {
static AFAppDotNetAPIClient *_sharedClient = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    _sharedClient = [[AFAppDotNetAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AFAppDotNetAPIBaseURLString]];
    _sharedClient.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer new];
});

return _sharedClient;
```

}

Then, I've tried to parse the result by using the NSXMLParseDelegate protocol but I can't get any data. The links are valid.

```
+ (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)globalTimelinePostsWithBlock {
 return [[AFAppDotNetAPIClient sharedClient] GET:@"http://www.enetpulse.com/wp-content/uploads/sample_xml_feed_enetpulse_soccer.xml" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSXMLParser* parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:operation.responseData];

     [parser setDelegate:(id<NSXMLParserDelegate>)self];
     BOOL result = [responseObject parse];

} failure:nil];}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict  {
NSLog(@"found");
```

} ...

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this answer might be late..

Why don't you try something like this..

```
NSURL *urlLink = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlLink];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSXMLParser *XMLParser = (NSXMLParser*)responseObject;
        NHXmlParser *myParser = [[NHXmlParser alloc] init];
        XMLParser.delegate = myParser;
        [XMLParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];
        [XMLParser parse];
        myParser.delegate = self;

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *request, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"Error:------>%@", [error description]);
    }];
}
```

This is working fine for me.